# How to obtain the immediate substring between the two specific characters before a (*.*) formatted file [abc.tx, file.html etc]

Tags: c#, string, substring

Given a string filepath how to obtain the substring representing the directory name that contains the file in the given string path. for example, `\\subfolder\\abc.txt` or
`\\folder\\subfolder\\abc.txt`   how can i easily obtain subfolder string between the two backslashes `\\` ?

Comment: thanks, apparently i figured out too 

string directoryFullPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(file);
string directoryName = Path.GetFileName(directoryFullPath);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [FileInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.aspx) and [DirectoryInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.aspx) classes, like this -

```
FileInfo file = new FileInfo(@"C:\folder\subfolder\abc.txt");
DirectoryInfo dir = file.Directory;
string dirName = dir.Name;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the fileinfo class for you main operations: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo_properties.aspx

You can also use the String.Split to split on the "\" character: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx

```
string file = "\\folder\\subfolder\\abc.txt";

FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(file);

string directory = fi.DirectoryName;

string[] folderNames = directory.Split(new string [] {"\\"}, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Comment: directory will be `\\folder\\subfolder`

Comment: Ok, I see now, when "subfolder" was specified, that was the value he was requesting to find. I misunderstood it a little. I'm willing to admit that my solution isn't 100%

Answer (score 0):

I think it may help you

```
        string path = @"\folder\subfolder\abc.txt";
        var arr=path.Split('\\');

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
        {
            //Select the required value
            string val = arr[i];
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   one more way to get "subfolder" from the path....

    string path = "\\folder\\subfolder\\abc.txt";
    var arr=path.Split('\\');
    string val = arr[arr.Length-2];
```

assuming in "path" we will get string in above format...

Comment: Your code does not work, the output would be an empty string. No need to use "@" if you are using "//" (Double Backslashes).....

Comment: @PrateekSingh now is it ok ???

by da way i was just showing the concept.. dats it...